# factanal() argument: lower

Tags: r, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

What is the purpose of the `lower` element in the `control` argument of the `factanal` function?

It says "The lower bound for uniquenesses during optimization" from the documentation. I realized that the loading scores from a factor (ex. 3rd factor) in the latent model can be extremely different depending on if lower is low (0.005) or high (0.6), so I have had trouble deciding how many latent factors I should include in my model. It seems that when `lower` is higher, the loading score of the latter factor gets lower, but I do not know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation (check `?factanal`) says:

> The uniquenesses are technically constrained to lie in [0, 1][0,1],
> but near-zero values are problematical, and the optimization is done
> with a lower bound of control$lower, default 0.005 (Lawley & Maxwell,
> 1971, p. 32).

Uniqueness is the variance of the unique factors, in terms of linear regression is a kind of residual variance, and thus it cannot be zero. Situations with uniqueness equal to zero in factor analysis are known as ‘Heywood cases’.

Now, increasing `control$lower` to a threshold far from zero, implies that the required solution is to be found in a narrower interval than the original [0,1] at the risk of missing the maximum of the likelihood. Thus, in most practical cases this option should be left as default unless you know what you are doing.

In any case, this is not at all useful towards choosing the number of latent factors. For the latter, there are already [good methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis):

- Kaiser rule, e.g. all factors with eigenvalues $\geq 1$;
- Likelihood ratio test, e.g. the minimum amount of factors needed in order to not reject $H_0$;
- Scree plot.

Comment: Thanks, actually , I calculated log-likelihood manually (to perform the nested LRT test) from each latent model using loading scores from factanal(), but I realized the scores were directly affected by lower bounds of uniqueness that was set by 'lower', and hence my question. How else you would perform the likelihood ratio test on latent models?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _calculate LR test on latent models_ since 'latent models' is a huge class of many different things. Anyway, you don't need to calculate LR test by hand since `factanal` already gives you the p-value.

Comment: I would like to perform a likelihood ratio test to compare which one is better: 2- or 3-factor model. I planned to use `fit$criteria['objective']`, where `fit` is an object from `factanal`, to perform the ratio test by treating it as log-likelihood. For some reason, the p-values returned from `factanal` are not helpful because they are far too low.

Comment: @SamMin perhaps you are trying to perform a different test other than LR? As I wrote above, for the LR test there is no need for manual ad error-prone implementation. On the other hand, the LR test will typically favour complex models, especially if the sample size is large. For this reason, the aforementioned criteria are typically applied jointly.